# regex to change a character at the end of a sentence

Tags: javascript, regex

> i want to change a character at the end of a line/sentence, i tried to find the regex but it didn't work...
>   **Ex:** if i type "blabladir" i want it to change it like "blabladr",,"dirblabladir" => "dirblabladr" etc etc...

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#ta_1").keyup(function(event) {
  
 var text2 = $(this).val();
  
 text2 = text2.replace(/(*)d(i)r/g, "dr");
  
 $("#ta_1").val(text2);

});
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
  
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
</head>
  
<body>
  
 <textarea id="ta_1" rows="5" cols="28" ></textarea>
  
</body>
  
</html>
```

Comment: use `$` for end of line

Comment: @PavelGatnar not working :(

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to change the regular expression to a one, which requires a character before the text to replace.

```
text2.replace(/(.)dir$/g, "$1dr");
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#ta_1").keyup(function(event) {     
        var text2 = $(this).val();

        text2 = text2.replace(/(.)dir$/g, "$1dr");
        $("#ta_1").val(text2);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="ta_1" rows="5" cols="28" ></textarea>
```

Comment: @Nina Scholz yes sir but it changes at the beginning too :/ i just want to change it at the end...

Comment: @Nina Scholz yes sir but it is not working after a space, i mean " dirblabla" => "drblabla" it is working only once

Comment: its a timing  problem. if you type `' dir'`, then the dir *is at the end*. if you type more, then it's not anymore at the end, but in between. so what you want is a check if the typing is going on and revert the change.

Answer (score 0):

Use '$' quantifier in your regex expression.

'$' finds the match at the end of the string. It returns NULL otherwise.

change your regex to:

`text = text.replace(/dir$/g, "dr");`

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#ta_1").keyup(function(event) {     
        var text2 = $(this).val();

        text2 = text2.replace(/([a-zA-Z])dir$/g, "$1dr");
 
        $("#ta_1").val(text2);
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
  
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
</head>
  
<body>
  
 <textarea id="ta_1" rows="5" cols="28" ></textarea>
  
</body>
  
</html>
```

> well after a little bit work i found a closest answer myself :) except for "dirdirdir", if you find a better answer please post it ;) !!